# Bash reliable way to test file exists

Tags: bash, shell, files, test

I recently found that bash `test -e` doesn't work with circular symlink.

```
ln -s ./test ./test
if [[ -e ./test ]]; then echo "exists"; fi
#this won't echo.
```

so I need to use `-L` then `-e` to do it

```
if [[ -L ./test || -e ./test ]]; then echo "exists"; fi
```

While this do fix my problem, I started to wonder if there's any other corner cases that `-e` doesn't cover.

What other corner cases exists? Is there a portable and easy way to reliably detect a file exists?

Comment: What is a circular symlink? Is `test` a directory

Comment: @daisy Suppose `test` does not exist, then `ln -s ./test test`.  This is a symbolic link that points to itself.  This doesn't seem very useful to me, but that's what a circular symbolic link is

Comment: And -f is insufficient ?

Comment: What is your use case? `stat file >/dev/null 2>&1` exits with failure if the file does not exist _or_ some directory on the path to `file` lacks execute permission (lacking read is okay!), and success in all (?) other cases, whether `file` is a file, symlink, directory, etc.

Comment: You can try `ls -d ./test &>/dev/null  && echo "exists"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the circular link, it's the symlink pointing to a file that doesn't exist. The same thing will happen any time you point a symlink to any file that doesn't exist.

From the `test` man page:

> If file is a symbolic link, test will fully dereference it and then
>   evaluate the expression against the file referenced, except for the -h
>   and -L primaries.

This is the only edge case for `test` mentioned in its man page.